# How to copy paste FileField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is how i upload file from form to FileField in the backend:

```
the_file    = request.FILES['newProfilePicture']
the_customer = Customer.objects.first()
the_customer.profile_picture = the_file
the_customer.save()
```

But here is the problem, how do i get that filefield and then "copy paste" it to another object that has a different "upload_to" data?

The Customer object:

```
class Customer( models.Model ):
    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/customer/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

The Customer_Alternative object:

```
class Customer_Alternative( models.Model ):
       profile_picture  = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/customer-alternative/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

My current problem is that when i do the followings, it simply use the same picture instead of "copy-pasting" it to the new directory:

```
old_customer = Customer.objects.all().first()
new_customer_alternative = Customer_Alternative( profile_picture=old_customer.profile_picture, )
new_customer_alternative.save()
```

So if i delete the FileField on that Customer object, it will also delete the data of the Customer_Alternative. Is there anyway to "copy paste" the data instead?

I tried to do a deep copy, but failed?

```
old_customer = Customer.objects.all().first()
new_customer_alternative = Customer_Alternative( profile_picture=old_customer.profile_picture, )
new_customer_alternative.profile_picture.file = ContentFile(old_customer.profile_picture.read())
new_customer_alternative.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a deep copy of the filefield, I found a link which maybe useful: [Force deep copy of Django FileField object (mainly new file itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270812/force-deep-copy-of-django-filefield-object-mainly-new-file-itself)